# Can this dual LP be solved?

Tags: linear-programming

The primal problem is as follows:

$\min w=2x+4y+5z+3q$

subject to
$$
\begin{split}
 -x - 2y + 2z &\geq 40\\
-3x - 2z -  q &\geq -100\\
  x - 2y -  z + 4q &\geq 50
\end{split}
$$

I have transformed it into dual LP and obtained:

$\max v=40a-100b+50c$

subject to

$$
\begin{split}
-a-3b+c \leq 2\\
-2a-2c \leq 4\\
2a-2b-c \leq 5\\
-b+4c \leq 3
\end{split}
$$

I've tried using excel solver for the primal LP and obtained the answers. I need to solve this problem by using the dual approach but I can't proceed with the simplex table for the dual. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LinearProgramming%5B%7B-40%2C100%2C-50%7D%2C+%7B%7B1%2C+3%2C-1%7D%2C%7B1%2C+0%2C1%7D%2C%7B-2%2C+2%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C+1%2C-4%7D%7D%2C+%7B-2%2C-2%2C-5%2C-3%7D%5D